# Radio static caused by windscreen wipers

Tags: radio, automotive, emc, electromagnetic, interference

I was driving past a radio station transmitter of the radio station I was listening to. I turned on my windscreen wipers, which caused a noticeable static to be emitted through the speakers for the entirety I held the lever. The static intensified as I approached the transmitter and faded as I drove away. I have never witnessed this situation before and the radio within my car operates normally without issue.

How does the electrical signal that causes my windscreen wipers to operate cause a static to be played through the radio when passing by a radio transmitter? When trying a number of times, I pulled the windscreen wiper for a short period such that the wiper did not move and the sound was audible, making me think it has to do with electromagnetic interference. I am unsure how the power sent to the windscreen wipers would cause it considering that there are a number of other electrical signals transmitted throughout the vehicle and the signal would be weak.

Comment: The strong RF signal was probably overloading the front end of the radio.

Comment: AM or FM reception? Frequency band?

Comment: FM reception. It was in the 90 to 100 MHz range @Andyaka.

Comment: How ditcha pull the w screen wipers when you re driving ?

Comment: It's a lever behind the steering wheel @user1999

Comment: _"... for the entirety I held the lever"_ - what is this lever for, and why did you hold it 'for the entirety'? Which radio station and exactly where did you drive past it?

Comment: The lever is used to turn on the windscreen wipers. The radio station is 89.3 Gulf FM and the location is here: https://www.google.com/maps/@-33.9484784,137.670927,3a,75y,252.55h,61.98t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sF1OBQEXqx35koGRJ5NqEUw!2e0!7i13312!8i6656